# No shadows on menus in Firefox 91

Tags: firefox, themes, menu, gtk3

After upgrade to Firefox 91, the menus in Firefox no more have shadows around them. This looks ugly and makes the menus less visible on top of the webpage. Is there any way I can bring them back? Maybe some tweak in theme's CSS?

Firefox menus were always styled a bit differently from other applications menus (for example note the difference on separators and submenu arrows on enclosed screenshots), but at least they had borders similar to the other applications, up to the latest release, when the borders disappeared.

This is how the menu looks on latest Firefox:
[image]

This is how the menu looks in other applications (here GIMP):
[image]

And this is how the menu did look in old versions of Firefox (this screenshot is from Firefox 84, which I keep aside due to Flash support, but all versions up to 91 did have similar shadows around menus):
[image]

BTW. This seems to be independent from desktop theme used, with all themes there are no shadows.